# how to access and print the value of inner index in python list

Tags: python

I have a list of strings i will like to access and print its inner elements as shown below:

```
mylist = ['apple', 'balls', 'camera', 'dough', 'eleven']
specified_index = random.choices((range(len(mylist))), k=len(mylist))
print("specified_index =", specified_index)
merged_index = [mylist[tt] for tt in specified_index]
print("merged_index =", merged_index)
```

The result of merged_index keeps printing the words found at specified_index.
Sample Output:

```
specified_index = [2, 3, 4, 0, 1]
merged_index = ['camera', 'dough', 'eleven', 'apple', 'balls']
```

**What i want instead is to keep printing the corresponding letter of specified_index -not the whole words** even if the list is shuffled.
#For example: **My preferred output == "mgeaa"**

```
specified_index = [2, 3, 4, 0, 1]
merged_index = ['caMera', 'douGh', 'elevEn', 'Apple', 'bAlls']
```

**Note:::** I tried

```
import more_itertools as mit
merged_list = mit.random_product(mylist)
```

but it doesn't allow me to maintain same specified_index whenever mylist is shuffled
#Other answers i found does not really solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access each element in mylist at the same time as iteration through `specified_index`. You can do that with `zip`. Then use `''.join` to get the desired result.

```
mylist = ['apple', 'balls', 'camera', 'dough', 'eleven']
specified_index = random.choices((range(len(mylist))), k=len(mylist))
print("specified_index =", specified_index)
merged_index = ''.join([elem[tt] for elem, tt in zip(mylist, specified_index)])
print("merged_index =", merged_index)
```

```
specified_index = [2, 0, 0, 2, 4]
merged_index = pbcue
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the words in `mylist` are longer than or equal to the length of `mylist` a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) could be used to achieve your desired result:

```
>>> import random
>>> mylist = ['apple', 'balls', 'camera', 'dough', 'eleven']
>>> specified_index = random.choices((range(len(mylist))), k=len(mylist))
>>> specified_index
[2, 3, 4, 0, 1]
>>> merged_index = [f'{mylist[i][:i]}{mylist[i][i].upper()}{mylist[i][i+1:]}' for i in specified_index]
>>> merged_index
['caMera', 'douGh', 'elevEn', 'Apple', 'bAlls']
>>> merged_word = ''.join(mylist[i][i] for i in specified_index)
>>> merged_word
'mgeaa'
```

As an aside, since python employs [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) using [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) for variables in Python (`mylist`) is kinda [sus](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sus) [ngl](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ngl)... consider using `words` or something else that doesn't reference the type next time [fr fr](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=for%20real).